# How to know the type of change of DocumentChange using Cloud Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have a listener for any change happens it works fine but i can't get the type of change is it Delete, Add or modify

```
Firestore.instance.collection('groups').snapshots().listen((data) {
        data.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
          print('documentChanges ${change.document.data}');
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [Google Cloud Firestore API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentChange), you can access to the type of `DocumentChange` with `getType()`

In case of the Flutter plugin that would be the property `type` (you can check the `DocumentChange` class of the plugin here: [document_change.dart](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_change.dart)). It contains this `enum` for the `type` property:

> ```
> /// An enumeration of document change types.
> enum DocumentChangeType {
>   /// Indicates a new document was added to the set of documents matching the
>   /// query.
>   added,
>
>   /// Indicates a document within the query was modified.
>   modified,
>
>   /// Indicates a document within the query was removed (either deleted or no
>   /// longer matches the query.
>   removed,
> }
>
> /// The type of change that occurred (added, modified, or removed).
> final DocumentChangeType type;
> ```

So in your case you should be able to do:

```
change.type == DocumentChangeType.added
```